# Running a macro in a for loop for multiple work books

Tags: python, xlwings

So I have three files right now, 1. Template file with the rater, which performs calculations, and two files with data that gets copied to the rater.

I wrote a code that loops through the files assigns them to a work book  copies the data from the work book to the rater, runs the macro to perform the calculations, and copies the output column back to the work book/save/close.

It works fine if I run it on its own e.g not in the loop, however when I try to run it within the loop it gives me a com_error.

Below is the code.

```
app=xw.apps.add()
rater=app.books.open(path)
#macros to run
clear_all=rater.macro('clear_batch')
batch_rater=rater.macro('batch_rater')

for file_name in filenames:

    os.chdir(input_path)
    wb=xw.Book(file_name)    

    comp_data=wb.sheets("Data for Rater").range("copy_range").value
    rater.sheets("Batch Rater").range("b23").value=comp_data



    batch_rater()


    comp_premium=rater.sheets("Batch Rater").range("premium_copy_py").value
    #wb.sheets("Batch Rater").range("AQ23").options(transpose=True).value=test
    if file_name=="cien_cova_roofage_rooftype.xlsx":
        wb.sheets("All Company Premium").range("AQ67202").options(transpose=True).value=comp_premium
    elif file_name=='cien_cova_yearbuilt.xlsx':
        wb.sheets("All Company Premium").range("AQ12002").options(transpose=True).value=comp_premium


    clear_all()


    os.chdir(output_path)
    wb.save(str(file_name[:-4])+'_batch_output.xlsx')
    wb.close()
```

Appreciate any input/advice thanks

Comment: can you provide the error in the question?

Comment: self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),

com_error: (-2147417856, 'System call failed.', None, None)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the root cause of your error but you are setting the variable `file_name` manually after it is assigned in the for loop. So every loop will have the same `file_name`.

Comment: Its not, I added that so I can manually run it one file at a time. But I see how that can be confusing